# C++ Cross Thread Exception Throwing

Tags: c++, timer

Hello I am currently trying to implement a timer in C++ that automatically logs out a user after a certain amount of time the user is idle. What I would like to do is when the user enters a command the NotIdleException is called from main and the thread running the sleep for 15 minutes function is restarted from the beginning of the timer

The Code for the timer is located here
http://pastebin.com/tw1YGcmu

The problem I am running into is I would like to call this exception from the main thread and have it be handled by the try catch in the timer thread. Is there any way I could do this in C++ (cross platform!)?

Comment: `boost::asio` already has [timers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/timers.html); `boost::thread`s can be interrupted while sleeping ([`thread::interrupt`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.interrupt)), which throws an exception in the interrupted thread.

Comment: Include the relevant code in the question, while trying to keep the size reasonable. Links in questions or answers are fine, as long as the question/answer can stand by itself *without* the link.

Comment: You want to use exceptions to pass (non-exceptional) messages between threads? Please don't this is probably the worst way to implement that.

Answer (score 1):

I looked briefly at your code, but there is no example of how it would be called/used.

If you're looking for a way to transfer exceptions across threads, an std::future (in C++11) will propogate an exception when its get() member function is called, if the thread populating the future generates an exception.
[std::future::get](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get)

You could also look at std::condition_variable, which can notify threads (also a C++11 feature).

It's hard to say, because there's no clear statement of how your code would be used, but I think std::condition_variable would be a better design for what you're trying to do.